# Issues Linking gdi32 library for GLFW on MinGW-W64

Tags: linker, glfw, static-linking

I am having the follow error building with my makefile:

```
g++ -Wall  -o build/chess-gui src/*.cpp src/vendor/glad/src/glad.c  -Isrc/  -Isrc/vendor/glad/include  -Isrc/vendor/glfw/include  -Lsrc/vendor/glfw/lib-mingw-w64  -lgdi32  -lopengl32  -lglfw3

C:\Program Files\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: src/vendor/glfw/lib-mingw-w64/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x10f): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'
C:\Program Files\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: src/vendor/glfw/lib-mingw-w64/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x14e): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
C:\Program Files\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: src/vendor/glfw/lib-mingw-w64/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

From what I understand, these functions are from `libgdi32.a`, which I tried to link above. I even copied the library to the same directory as `glfw3`, which I know links, so I am stuck.

I've read online that the ordering of libraries for this matters, but I've tried multiple ways and none of them work for me.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!